# A folder for multiple django apps

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to change the structure of my project. In fact, I would like to have an `apps` folder where I can stock all my project's apps.

In this case I making a `member` app into the given folder. If I try to run the project I have this error:

`django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'member'. Check that 'apps.member.apps.MemberConfig.name' is correct.`

In my `settings.py` I configured my `INSTALLED_APPS` as follow:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.member.apps.MemberConfig',
]
```

Basically, I just want to have the following folder structure:

```
project_folder/
     ___ apps/
     ___ config/
```

For the rest of the settings folder here is the [GIST](https://gist.github.com/rubi0/cc0ab1316104e92f5461ff05bb84aab2)

More information:

Django version : 1.11

Python version: 3.5.2

OS: Ubuntu 16

Comment: `MemberConfig.name` is incorrect. What about to add content of this file to the question?

Comment: Why did you go all the way to `MemberConfig`? Why not just do `apps.member`?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov This is a recommended way to include applications since Django 1.7 if you want to configure them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change "apps.member.apps.MemberConfig" to "apps.member"

Comment: thanks @rrrub I'm glad to hear that and thanks for your vote.